# Setting custom shortcut for applications not working

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, shortcut

I'm a new Macbook user and still struggling with iOS. I've installed `iterm2` and would like to setup a shortcut for it (preferably `control+command+T`

I went to `System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts` and added a shortcut for iterm2 there

[image]

However, when actually pressing the shortcut nothing happens...

Comment: You could look in iTerm's `Preferences -> Keys -> Hotkey`: At the bottom there's _Show/hide all windows with a system-wide hotkey_.

Comment: Thanks, specifying the hotkey in the iterm settings worked! Could you place it as an answer then I'll accept it

Comment: This question is closed by someone, and I don't have the possibility to answer to it. Only comments are allowed. So that's what I used to give an answer.